# How to automate database backup hosted in Yahoo small Business

Tags: php, mysql, windows, amazon-s3, database-backups

My website is hosted in yahoo small business, The database server is MySQL, I want to automate db backup, My main requirement is backup files must go to amazon bucket.

Yahoo small business does not provide access to putty, which could be used to run the backup script.

So, I have scheduled a task locally(windows machine) which calls the php backup script on the server and saves the backup files to folder in the server, Now i want to save these files to amazon bucket instead of folder, How to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't quote me entirely on this but, Yahoo in general is very very very limiting in what they allow there clients to do. Best you can do that I can think of off the top of my head is run another scheduled task on your windows machine that will physically download the file then pass it to the bucket.

Though pending yahoo doesn't limit it severely like they used to you may even be able to get away with the concept of another scheduled item on your windows machine. Where it just pings another script on your yahoo that will use the Amazon S3 api's to drop the file in a bucket.

All in all though your best bet is get off of yahoo, get a cheap VPS where you are open to do a lot more with your server than a standard shared system especially one that limits its customers 10 fold. I host many of my sites through myhosting.com I have a vps account, i got something like 200 gigs of storage a terabyte of transfer and so many more perks for 36 dollars a month. And I can do virtually anything I want with the server as if it were my own linux based machine to do such with. Anyway thats off topic. The point I am ultimately trying to make is getting on an account like that you can run CRON jobs that is the same thing as the scheduler on your machine but on the same server as your site you want to back up, so no worries about a disconnect between server and home brew machine. You will also be able to install other 3rd party concepts that may secure your transfer to Amazon every night or do many of other things as well.. Just food for thought. All in all staying on Yahoo is going to really limit your ability.